Problem in Deploying Python (Flask app) on Vercel
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for
import cv2
import cvzone
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import time
import random

It's Rock, Paper Scissors Game where the app takes camera permission and user can play with AI. The users' moves are detected by camera.
I have used all the above libraries and modules in my python(flask app) , I'm having problem in deploying this Flask app on vercel.
Error Message : Size of uploaded file exceeds 300MB

I'm trying to deploy the flask app of Vercel

you should ask admins of Vercel if they have some limit for uploaded files. Maybe you will have to split data in smaller files and later join them on server. But it is question for admins of Vercel, not for Stackoveflow.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.
